# Java TimeZoneOffset time conversion

Tags: java-8, timezone-offset

Using Jdk8.
I am trying to convert time actually just hours of the day (like 1130)  into DateTime. I am trying it 2 ways as below none of them work correctly. 1130 gets converted into 11:00 and another 3:00 none of them are correct. Is there also a 3rd way naming my Time Zone.

```
Long ltime = Long.parseLong("1130");
   Long  seconds = (ltime/100)*60*60;
   LocalDateTime tsutcDttime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    LocalDateTime lclDttime =   LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds), ZoneId.systemDefault());
 System.out.println("ZoneId.systemDefault: " +ZoneId.systemDefault());
 System.out.println("UTC LocalDateTime : "+ tsutcDttime); 
 System.out.println("Sys Def LocalDateTime : "+ lclDttime);
```

ZoneId.systemDefault: **America/Los_Angeles**

UTC LocalDateTime : 1970-01-01T**11:00**

Sys Def LocalDateTime : 1970-01-01T**03:00**

This problem got solved by below.

**Part2 of this problem** 
For some of my time components I have a Date and for some other I don't (but I have to convert everything into datetime anyway.

How do I add the actual date when I have it? I am not seeing a method LocalDate (date)? For others will simply let default to 1970 unless a better soln exists.
The below just puts the 1970 date:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(secondsOfDay, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

But when I have a date I would like to add it to secondsOfDay and create my DateTime- How. Like Date = Jan 1 2016 + secondsOfDay

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the string "1130" means 11 hours and 30 minutes you need to do the conversion to seconds separately for the hours and minutes:

```
long ltime = Long.parseLong("1130");

long hoursAsSeconds = (ltime / 100) * 60 * 60;
long minsAsSeconds = (ltime % 100) * 60;

long secondsOfDay = hoursAsSeconds + minsAsSeconds;
```

You can then use `LocalTime` to get the local time given the seconds:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(secondsOfDay);
```

You could also get the local time directly by parsing the time like this:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("1130", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm"));
```

From that you can get a `LocalDateTime` using something like:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), localTime);
```

Or a `ZonedDateTime` using:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), localTime, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression is causing the issue:

```
 Long  seconds = (ltime/100)*60*60;
```

Division operator returns integer value so you are loosing precision here.

```
1130/100 = 11.3 ~ 11
11 * 60*60 = 39600
11.3 * 60*60 = 40680
```

Division should be the last operation in your expression:

```
Long  seconds = (ltime*60*60)/100;
```

Comment: The "1130" string is presumably 11 hours and 30 minutes, this code treats the value as 1130 / 100 hours which is not the same.

Comment: @all Sorry for my goofy code, what was I thinking. Yes the solutions suggested will work. @greg-449 `LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("1130", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm"));` this is the exactly the elegant solution I was looking for - I knew something like this should exist. I have Part2 of this problem for some of my time components I have a Date and for some other I don't (but I have to convert everything into datetime anyway. How do I add the actual date when I have it? I am not seeing a method LocalDate (date)? For others will simply let default to 1970 unless a soln exists.

Comment: @Sam-T Sorry but I don't get what you are asking. Ask a new question with more details.

Comment: @greg-449 Let me add details in the main question.

Comment: Added new question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874557/java-how-to-add-time-and-date